# Why my Realtime Database Data is not showing anything in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am doing a Android Studio Project with Firebase but I can't view the data in the Realtime Database. It seems successfully connected because I can see my data in the Authentication (User) but not displaying in Realtime database. Please help me. I have also turn the rules into true. But still my Firebase data showing **south-masalaa-default-rtbd:null**

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(CustEmail, CustPass)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                User user = new User(CustName, CustEmail, CustPhoneNumber, CustPass );
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Successful Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Not successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Failed to register the user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is any of Toast messages displayed?

Comment: No there is no toast message displayed. But if i register the same email it displayed "Failed to register the user".

Comment: Is  your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: Im really sorry ...But what do you mean by triggered? (new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()) this is still anonymous  ...is that because of that

Comment: Is your onComplete even called?

Comment: Yes. its called

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I already import this import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener; in my project. And if the onComplete is not be called how can it store the email in database? Im sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: Is there anything i can do ???

Comment: Make sure it's called, otherwise the code inside will node be triggered.

Comment: How to know that its called or not ? Please provide a code

Comment: I recommend performing some debugging yourself, and telling us the results. For example, if you put a breakpoint on the call to `setValue` and another one on `if(task.isSuccessful())` and run. the app in the debugger, does it reach either/both of those breakpoints? And if so, do the values of all variables on that line look correct to you?

Comment: Hello Frank..i have set the breakpoint and perform debugging ....but it doesn't display any thing in the frame. But from the second **public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)** till the } has no 1 tick....is that the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the full database URL in the call to `getInstance()` like this:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL").getReference()`